# How to use an argument in one class, in another class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, init

```py
class Grid:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class Rover:
    def __init__(self,xr,yr,direction):
        self.xr = xr
        self.yr = yr
        self.direction = direction
```

First I want to make a grid `mygrid(5,5)` than I will make a rover `myrover(5,5,H)` if the rovers coordinates lie outside the grid `roverx<gridx or roverx>gridx same with y` than it will be an invalid rover

How can I use the the value (which will be set later on) in one class in another one as a criteria?

Answer (score 0):

If the Rover needs to know about the Grid, you have tot tell it about the Grid.

Something like:

```
class Rover:
    def __init__(self, xr, yr, direction, grid):
        if xr>= grid.x or yr>= grid.y:
            print("Invalid Rover")
        ...
```

First create a grid

```
gr = Grid(5,5)
```

and use that when you create a Rover

```
r = Rover(2, 3, 4, gr)
```

Comment: Is there a way for rover to check writing only r = Rover(2, 3, H). I want it to acknowledge the Grid automatically.